# Постоянно падает интернет

Tags: модемы

Постоянно отваливается интернет. Иногда восстанавливается сам, иногда приходится запускать диагностику. После диагностики выявляются следующие проблемы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не соответствует тематике ru.so

Comment: @nörbörnën  есть список "разрешенных" тем или же это твое личное ощущение, что не по теме?

Comment: @Николай, возможно ваш роутер идет на перезагрузку. попробуйте пингдовать роутер во время ошибки, попробуйте посмотреть настройки конфигурации. желательно смотреть в консоле. когда появятся новая информация - добавляете в вопрос

Comment: список разрешенных тем есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic